creating a certificate from app store connect api
i'm using this code for create a certificate from api
POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates
and this is the data iam sending
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "certificateType": "IOS_DISTRIBUTION",
      "csrContent":"XXXX"
    },
    "type": "certificates"
  }
}


but i cant get a way to get csr content?
can i genereate this without the classic manual way?
a way to generate csr
